# SQL Server 2008 DELETE taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-delete

When I try to delete a from a table that has foreign key restraint it take a long time. It does not complete after 3 minutes. If I do it like this it takes a long time:

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DELETE FROM [T1] 
       WHERE
    ROLEID = (SELECT ROLEID FROM T2 
    WHERE
     NAME = 'GM')

     ROLLBACK
```

But the following executes immediately:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DELETE FROM [T1] 
       WHERE
    ROLEID = (5)
     ROLLBACK
```

Obviously the second query does not have a subquery, however I know that the subquery in my first query returns only 2 rows. Why would the first query take so long?

Comment: Ask yourself, how many times is that subquery being executed? Hint, it is more than you think.

Comment: If the subquery in the first version is returning two rows, then it should be generating an error.  Have you checked for that?  For multiple rows, you should be using `in` rather than `=`.

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? That will tell you what is taking so long.  If you can post it here that might help.

Comment: The replies from each one of you helped me to think about the bottle necks in my script and make corrections. I am posting my solution as an answer and would like feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT ROLEID 
    INTO #RIDS
FROM APPROLES
    WHERE
    NAME IN ( 'GM', 'MINOR', 'USER')

DELETE T1  FROM  [ROLEFUNCS]  T1
      INNER JOIN [#RIDS] T2 ON T2.ROLEID = T1.ROLEID

DELETE T3  FROM  [USERROLES]  T3
      INNER JOIN [#RIDS] T2 ON T2.ROLEID = T3.ROLEID

DELETE T4  FROM  [ROLES]  T4
      INNER JOIN [#RIDS] T2 ON T2.ROLEID = T4.ROLEID

DROP TABLE #RIDS
```